# Unbelievable Java equal test error

Tags: java, algorithm, int, equals

Please see the code and tell me your opinion
Even on my debugger it shows 102 == 102 that gives me false ... can you imagine ?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by Idris on 18/11/14.
 */
public class codingGame {


    static boolean exists(int[] ints, int k) {

        Integer j =  ints[ints.length/2];
        if (j.equals(k)){
            return true;
        }

        if (ints.length == 1) return false;


        if (k > j ) {
            int[] intb = Arrays.copyOfRange(ints, ints.length/2, ints.length);
            exists(intb, k);

        }

        if (k < j ) {
            int[] intb = Arrays.copyOfRange(ints, 0, ints.length/2);
            exists(intb, k);

        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        int[] ints = {-9, 14, 37, 102};
        System.out.println(exists(ints, 102)); // true
        System.out.println(exists(ints, 36)); // false

    }

}
```

Comment: Functions don't automatically return what functions they call return.

Comment: Also, `Integer` is not `int`. This is important.

Comment: You probably want to put `// false` instead of `// true` or indicate that it is expected rather than actual.

Comment: so how to return what the called function return?

Answer (score 5):

You forgot you're `return` statements on the recursion. You need to use `return exists(intb, k);` to return the true that may occur within the recursion, otherwise the code will always return false if `j.equals(k)` is false.

```
static boolean exists(int[] ints, int k) {

    Integer j =  ints[ints.length/2];
    if (j.equals(k)){
        return true;
    }

    if (ints.length == 1) return false;


    if (k > j ) {
        int[] intb = Arrays.copyOfRange(ints, ints.length/2, ints.length);
        return exists(intb, k);

    }

    if (k < j ) {
        int[] intb = Arrays.copyOfRange(ints, 0, ints.length/2);
        return exists(intb, k);

    }

    return false;
}
```